# Wicket: How to "pass" AJAX behavior to wrapped form component?

Tags: model, wicket, word-wrap

if I have an input wrapped in a div (together with other stuff),
how can I pass to that input whatever beavior is added to the wrapper?

Example:
   Component HTML goes like `<div> <img> <input> ...`
   Then I'd like to add it like `add( new MyComponent("foo", model).add( new AjaxEventBehavior("onupdate"){ ... }` (but that doesn't work since only `FormComponent` can receive (AjaxEventBehavior`s).

I assume I could move this behavior object from wrapper to input, but don't know where - is there some "after construction" listener?
Or should I do it completely different, like passing the behavior as a parameter?
The reason to keep it like above is to make it transparent for the user of the component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could override the `MarkupContainer#add(Behavior... behaviors)` method of the wrapping component. This would of course mean that the wrapping component could never receive any behaviors:

```
public class MyWrappingComponent extends Panel {
    private TextField<?> field;

    // Constructors and stuff..

    @Override
    public Component add(Behavior... behaviors) {
        field.add(behaviors);
        return this;
    }
}
```

One option is to separate the wrapping component to be a [`Border`](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/border/Border.html), which can be used to surround components with content. This would, however, reduce the "transparency" of the wrapping element. (See the example on the [Javadoc page](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/border/Border.html)).

```
public class MyWrappingBorder extends Border {
    public MyWrappingBorder(String id) {
        // add the <img />
        // add the <div />
    }
    ...
 }

 // The markup
 <wicket:border>
     <div>
        <img />
        <wicket:body /> <!-- Will be replaced with the added content -->
     </div>
 </wicket:border>
```

Then use it like this:

```
 add(new MyWrappingBorder("border")
     .add(new TextField<String>("input").add(/* the behaviors */)));
```

With this kind of markup

```
 <div wicket:id="border">
     <input type="text" wicket:id="input" />
 </div>
```

The `Border` approach would enable you to reuse the border component without the `TextField? component. E.g., if you want to add a drop-down:

```
 add(new MyWrappingBorder("border")
     .add(new DropDownChoice<String>("input", listOfChoices)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Include an abstract method in your wrapper that returns the component.

```
public abstract class WrapperComponent extends Panel 
{
       public WrapperComponent(String id)
       {
              super(id);

              add(getInnerComponent("whateveridyouwant"));

              //Other wrapper stuff
       } 

      public abstract Component getInnerComponent(String id);         
}
```

Then calling the WrapperComponent will force you to Override the getInnerComponent method.

```
WrapperComponent wrapperComponent = new WrapperComponent("wrapperComponent")
{
     @Override
     public Component getInnerComponent(String id)
     {
          TextField textfield = new TextField(id);
          textField.add(behavior);
          return textfield; 
     }  

}
```

This way allows you to define what innerComponent and behavior you want when you actually decided to use the WrapperComponent. It gives more control over what you can do with the innerComponent.

Hope you find this helpful.